# VisualStudioTeamServices Link item with Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

i'm using VisualStudioTeamServices and I created a new project with a new Git-Repo.

Then I created a new backlog-item with one new task (ID: #140)

Now I created a file on my local repo and wanted to commit the file and link this commit to my task(#143).

I used this command

```
git commit -am "test #140"
```

and

```
git push
```

The commit was pushed to my VSTS-Repo but the link to the commit in the task was not created.

The same problem with Tools like GitKranken,...

Does anyone know where the failure is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
You have to enable the option
"Automatically create links for work items mentioned in a commit comment." in the options for you repository in VSTS

[image]

Comment: Note that this in enabled by default, this someone disabled it on your instance.

Answer (score 1):

No matter git command line or other git GUI, the commit message format `#ID` should be recognized.

You just need to **refresh your web page** (such as backlog page), and then open the task which id is 140, then you will find the commit in Development.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My problem was the disabled option. See my answer with the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, you can mark your own answer 24 hours later. And it can help others who have similar questions :)